# How to reuse implementation of From<&str> and From<&String> in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have some code like this in my Rust project:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash)]
pub struct FQN<'a>(&'a str);

impl<'a> From<&'a str> for FQN<'a> {
    fn from(fqn: &'a str) -> Self {
        if fqn.split('.').count() < 2 {
            panic!("Invalid FQN: {}", fqn);
        }
        FQN(fqn)
    }
}

impl<'a> From<&'a String> for FQN<'a> {
    fn from(fqn: &'a String) -> Self {
        if fqn.split('.').count() < 2 {
            panic!("Invalid FQN: {}", fqn);
        }
        FQN(fqn)
    }
}
```

In my case this struct is project-internal and I'm the one constructing strings, so I want it to panic if there's an error (I don't want to return a Result type as in https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html).

Is there a way to deduplicate this code so that I do not have to repeat the implementation for both &String and &str?

I tried implementing like this, but then the borrow checker yells that I cannot return a value owned by the current function:

```rust
impl<'a, T> From<T> for FQN<'a>
where
    T: AsRef<str> + 'a,
{
    fn from(fqn: T) -> Self {
        let fqn_ref = fqn.as_ref();
        if fqn_ref.split('.').count() < 2 {
            panic!("Invalid FQN: {}", fqn_ref);
        }
        FQN(fqn_ref)
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple here... any pointers?

Comment: Since `&String` coreces to `&str` [there isn't really a need to implement `From<&'a String>` at all](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2c02e8b9b0bd74dafca2810ed62df350).

Comment: @cafce25 It may be needed with generics.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I can't think of a case - generics can also use `AsRef<str>`, from which you can extract a `&str`.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a reference:

```rust
impl<'a, T> From<&'a T> for FQN<'a>
where
    T: AsRef<str>,
{
    fn from(fqn: &'a T) -> Self {
        let fqn_ref = fqn.as_ref();
        if fqn_ref.split('.').count() < 2 {
            panic!("Invalid FQN: {}", fqn_ref);
        }
        FQN(fqn_ref)
    }
}
```

However, I think this is over-engineering, and just calling one impl from the other is fine:

```rust
impl<'a> From<&'a str> for FQN<'a> {
    fn from(fqn: &'a str) -> Self {
        if fqn.split('.').count() < 2 {
            panic!("Invalid FQN: {}", fqn);
        }
        FQN(fqn)
    }
}

impl<'a> From<&'a String> for FQN<'a> {
    fn from(fqn: &'a String) -> Self {
        fqn.as_str().into()
    }
}
```